# Multi level login user and admin using session?

Tags: java, android, authentication, session

I have a project to create a login application in Android studio using multi-level session and user login and admin login with different activities.

For example, if the admin click the login button then it goes to the admin activity. If the user clicks then it goes to the user  to user activity. All this already works; however, the problem is if I login with admin and close the application by pressing the back button twice without logging out, after that I try to reopen the application, but what appears is user `activity(**MainActivity**) not admin activity(**AdminActivity**)` ....

Do you have a solution to help me? Sorry if my English bad/

```
package com.example.ilvan.gogas;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.ilvan.gogas.app.AppController;
import com.example.ilvan.gogas.util.Server;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    EditText txtusername, txtpassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    TextView btnRegister;


    int success;
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;

    private String url = Server.URL + "checkLogin.php";

    private static final String TAG = com.example.ilvan.gogas.Login.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public final static String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    public final static String TAG_ID = "user_id";
    public final static String TAG_USERTYPE = "user_type";

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Boolean session = false;
    String user_id, username,user_type;

    public static final String my_shared_preferences = "my_shared_preferences";
    public static final String session_status = "session_status";

    final String MESSAGE_NO_INTERNET_ACCESS = "No Internet Connection";
    final String MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_EMPTY = "Kolom Tidak Boleh Kosong";
    final String MESSAGE_LOGIN = "Logging in ...";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        {
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MESSAGE_NO_INTERNET_ACCESS,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_register);
        txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

        // Cek session login jika TRUE maka langsung buka halaman setelah login
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
        user_id = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_ID, null);
        username = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_USERNAME, null);
        user_type = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_USERTYPE, null);

        if (session) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, user_id);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String username = txtusername.getText().toString();
                String password = txtpassword.getText().toString();

                // mengecek kolom yang kosong
                if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                        checkLogin(username, password);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MESSAGE_NO_INTERNET_ACCESS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_EMPTY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                Login.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage(MESSAGE_LOGIN);
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (success == 1) {
                        String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String user_type = jObj.getString(TAG_USERTYPE);
                        String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                        Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // menyimpan login ke session
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                        editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                        editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        editor.commit();

                        // Memanggil halaman setelah login
                        if (session && user_type.contentEquals("penjual")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.ilvan.gogas.Login.this, MainActivityPenjual.class);
                            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                            intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                            intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("username : ", username);
                        Log.e("password : ",password);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                hideDialog();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, just override the onBackPressed method with your method to logout in the last activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();  
            logout();
      }
    }
```

And you define logout() method as you want.

Answer (score 0):

About your project, you can do it by several ways, and implementing more than one design pattern, but to keep it simple you can try the following...

Create a screen that serves as a User Roles management. A SplashScreen is handly with this. There you can check the User's type, and it helps you to maintain the separation of concerns.

Now we can see that you're checkin only the session on your onCreate method, but you ain't checking the `user_type`. Actually you need to do the same as in the Callback of your checkLogin method but this time validating the session's variable.

```
        if (session && user_type.contentEquals("admin")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.ilvan.gogas.Login.this, AdminActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So you're only getting inside the `MainActivity` regardless of the user type.

Hope this help you! Cheers... welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: I tried it but still can't,  i was edited my code above, pls check again

Comment: Hello, I can see the changes, but you still need to change the conditional that is below the instantiation of `user_type` and just above the btnLogin's click listener. Remove the session variable of the conditional below the "// Memanggil halaman setelah login" comment.